# StAX how do you preserve XML data exactly as is

Tags: java, stax

I have a requirement to retain some XML data exactly as it is received from another system. Here is an example of what we are receiving:

```
<SomeTag display="1 2 3 4 5 &lt;anotherTag>someValue&lt;/anotherTag>" />
```

When this is read in and then saved to our DB it is saved like this:

```
<SomeTag display="1 2 3 4 5 &lt;anotherTag&gt;someValue&lt;/anotherTag&gt;" />
```

I want to preserve the data exactly as is without it encoding the > sign.

Comment: Why?  The two forms are identical as far as any XML parser is concerned.  If you care about the difference then you shouldn't be using an XML API like StAX to process the data.  In fact you have no way of knowing when you get the attribute value from the StAX parser whether it was represented in the original bytes as `>`, `&gt;`, `&#x3E` or whatever.

Comment: I agree and that's what I thought. Just wanted to verify. Thanks All!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *only* have the StAX events then no, there's no way to achieve this, because when you get an attribute value of

```
1 2 3 4 5 <anotherTag>someValue</anotherTag>
```

from the StAX parser there's no way to know what the original bytes looked like - the greater than signs might have been `>` or `&gt;` or `&#x3E;`, all these forms will produce the same value when parsed and any XML parser must treat them as equivalent.

If you care about the precise original representation then you'll have to do this outside the XML world - save the original bytes somehow before they are parsed by the StAX parser, decode them using the correct character encoding, and store the resulting string directly into your database.

Answer (score 0):

If you saved the xml which you received from another system as string in a DB column without processing it would guarantee preserving it as is